# why can't I get css-lightbox for compass to work? (missing mixin error)

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I am attempting to use [compass-css-lightbox](https://github.com/ericam/compass-css-lightbox) as part of my compass/sass project. Despite following the installation instructions in the README I am unable to get it functioning.

Here are the steps I have gone through so far, just in case anyone can point out any glaring mistakes.

1. Installed the plugin using gem using the command line:
   $gem install css-lightbox
2. Added it to my project:
   $compass install css-lightbox
3. activate compass watch:
   compass watch
4. import css-lightbox (**@import "css-lightbox"** in my app.scss file)

To this point everything seems to be working correctly, the install gave confirmed messages at each stage, _lightbox.sass partial was created, the import compiled with out error but when I try to use any of the mixins mentioned in the documentation I get and undefined error:

```
error sass/app.scss (Line 54: Undefined mixin 'lightbox-with-default-styles'.)
```

Comment: There's not really enough information here to help you.  What files is app.scss importing?  It has to import either _lightbox.sass or css-lightbox in order for you to have access to the lightbox mixins.

Comment: @cimmanon Sorry if its not clear. In point 4. I added "css-lightbox" as an import in my app.scss file before making any reference to the mixin.  I also tried adding importing "lightbox" but the result was the same.

Comment: There's only one real guide on Compass Extensions:  http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/.  It focuses on building them, but it does show how they would be used towards the very end.  The reason the mixins aren't found in the generated file is because they're bundled within the css-lightbox gem.  It's done this way so that you don't have to copy/paste/maintain code between multiple projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem install css-lightbox` installs a stable version, which is 0.2.

But you're using documentation for a non-stable version (last released 0.3.beta.2, the master branch may have more changes).

To install the latest non-stable version, use:

```
gem install css-lightbox --pre
```

I'm filing a pull request to fix documentation.

Comment: Bundler doesn't accept the `--pre` flag. Any times on how to get this using the `Gemfile`?

Comment: @steven_noble, `gem "css-lightbox", "~> 0.3.beta.2"`.